# Select the complement of a set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Rails 3.0. I have two tables: Listings and Offers. A Listing `has-many` Offers. An offer can have `accepted` be `true` or `false`.

I want to select every Listing that does not have an Offer with `accepted` being true. I tried

```
Listing.joins(:offers).where('offers.accepted' => false)
```

However, since a Listing can have many Offers, this selects every listing that has non-accepted Offers, even if there is an accepted Offer for that Listing.

In case that isn't clear, what I want is the complement of the set:

```
Listing.joins(:offers).where('offers.accepted' => true)
```

My current temporary solution is to grab all of them and then do a filter on the array, like so:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    def self.open
        Listing.all.find_all {|l| l.open? }
    end

    def open?
        !offers.exists?(:accepted => true)
    end
end
```

I would prefer if the solution ran the filtering on the database side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to do essentially the same thing you're doing now, but in the database.

```
scope :accepted, lambda {
  joins(:offers).where('offers.accepted' => true)
} 

scope :open, lambda {
  # take your accepted scope, but just use it to get at the "accepted" ids
  relation = accepted.select("listings.id")

  # then use select values to get at those initial ids
  ids = connection.select_values(relation.to_sql)

  # exclude the "accepted" records, or return an unchanged scope if there are none
  ids.empty? ? scoped : where(arel_table[:id].not_in(ids))
}
```

I'm sure this could be done more cleanly using an outer join and grouping, but it's not coming to me immediately :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is working much more quickly than what I had. I'm mostly surprised that I hadn't found a solution to this on the internet - seems like it would be a relatively common problem.

Comment: A caveat - If there are no accepted answers, then `ids` is empty. This will make the `not_in` fail, and will select nothing! I added `ids |= [0]` right underneath the declaration of `ids`, and it works perfectly.